# React - Using controlled inputs inside Apollo Query component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo

I have a form inside an Apollo query component. All of it's inputs are controlled and look like so :

```
handleChangeValue = (value) => {
 this.setState(value);
}

<Input
 type="text"
 placeholder="Example"
 value={this.state.example}
 onChangeValue={this.handleChangeValue}
/>
```

The problem is that the value of the inputs rely on the state. So if I want to populate the inputs with data from the database, I'd have to do something like so:

```
<Query query={ACCOUNT_DETAILS} >
 {({ loading, error, data }) => {
  <Input
   type="text"
   placeholder="Example"
   value={data.example}
  />
 })
</Query>
```

But then, how would I update the value of my inputs ?

I thought about doing something like this:

```
value={this.state.example || data.example}
```

My inputs would use the data from state if it exists, otherwise it would use the data my query returned. This doesn't seem like the best solution to me, any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your component is not controlled. You are not passing onChange handler. How the value is going to be updated?

Comment: That's pretty much my question :-) I ended up creating two components. One with the query that passes down initial data as props to a child component containing the form. Seems to work perfectly !